# Creating a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to make a generic method for the following code:

```
foreach (var glitter in glitterpurchase.GlitterPurchaseDetails)
{
    var glitterInventory = _db.GlitterInventoriesRepository.GetAll(m => m.GlitterId == glitter.GlitterId);
    if (!glitterInventory.Any())
    {
        var newInventory = new GlitterInventory
        {
            GlitterId = glitter.GlitterId,
            Quantity = glitter.Quantity,
            TotalAmount = (decimal)glitter.Quantity * glitter.UnitPrice,
            UnitPrice = glitter.UnitPrice,
            CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
        };
        _db.GlitterInventoriesRepository.Insert(newInventory);
    }
    else                    
    {
        var updateInventory = glitterInventory.First();
        updateInventory.Quantity += glitter.Quantity;
        updateInventory.TotalAmount += (decimal)glitter.Quantity * glitter.UnitPrice;
        updateInventory.UnitPrice = (decimal)updateInventory.Quantity / updateInventory.TotalAmount;
        updateInventory.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        updateInventory.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        _db.GlitterInventoriesRepository.Update(updateInventory);
    }
}
```

The code above just simply updates the inventory. I want to make a generic method so that I can just call that method and update the inventory of different items ( classes ). I am not good with generics and after researching I have written the following code:

```
public virtual void UpdateInventory<PurchasedEntity, Inventory>(IEnumerable<PurchasedEntity> purchaseDetails, GenericRepository<Inventory> inventory, Expression<Func<Inventory, bool>> filterForInventory) 
            where PurchasedEntity : class
            where Inventory : class

{
    foreach (var item in purchaseDetails)
    {
        var glitterInventory = inventory.GetAll(filterForInventory);
        if (!glitterInventory.Any())
        {
            var newInventory = (Inventory)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Inventory), new object[] 
            {
                GlitterId = item.GlitterId,
                Quantity = item.Quantity,
                TotalPrice = (decimal)item.Quantity * item.UnitPrice,
                UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice,
                CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            });

            inventory.Insert(newInventory);
        }
        else
        {
            var updateInventory = glitterInventory.First();
            updateInventory.Quantity += item.Quantity;
            updateInventory.TotalAmount += (decimal)item.Quantity * item.UnitPrice;
            updateInventory.UnitPrice = (decimal)updateInventory.Quantity / updateInventory.TotalAmount;
            updateInventory.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            updateInventory.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            inventory.Update(updateInventory);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
'PurchasedEntity' does not contain a definition for 'GlitterId' and no extension method 'GlitterId' accepting a first argument of type 'PurchasedEntity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**How can I remove this error and get the properties of the class generically?**

I don't even know if the code I wrote is any good, so kindly if you can improve it, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You have defined a generic parameter constraint `where PurchasedEntity : class`, that means it would be allowed to use any type for this generic parameter. Thus, the generic method could only use methods, properties and fields from provided by Object class when working with the *item* variable -- because the Object class is the least common denominator amongst any types... You need to specify the constraint in a way that it is restricted to your (base) class which declare those GlitterId, Quantity, UnitPrice, etc... properties. Then the compiler will accept the code.

Comment: @elgonzo I can create a base class with Quantity, TotalPrice, UnitPrice, CreatedBy,CreatedDate but GlitterId should be generic as GlitterId can be PowderId, ColorId and so on. I have got a lot of inventory items and I am trying to write a generic method that can be used for all of them.

Comment: GlitterId is the name of a property, not a type. You cannot use generic parameters to "swap" the name of properties...

Comment: So is there no way to achieve what I want? can you suggest me something that might solve my problem/

Comment: There are ofcourse ways around this problem, but i do not really know what would be the best/most elegant for your needs... You could for example have your base class declare a 'general purpose' ID property, and each of your concrete implementations (Glitter, Powder, etc.) would set this ID property to whatever their GlitterID, PowderID or whatever is. If necessary, you could keep the GlitterID, PowderID etc. properties and make your class implementations so that their value is always in sync with the ID property declared in the base class...

Comment: Ok I am going to try this... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @elgonzo Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87080/discussion-between-syed-farjad-zia-zaidi-and-elgonzo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming not every `PurchasedEntity` has a `GlitterId` (and probably shouldn't depending on your domain).  So, define a suitable `Id` property on `PurchasedEntity` (or better yet extract it to an interface):

```
interface IPurchasedEntity{
    Guid Id {get;}
}
```

Update `GlitterInventory` to implement `IPurchasedEntity`:

```
public class GlitterInventory : IPurchasedEntity{
     Guid IPurchasedEntity.Id { get{ return GlitterId; }}
}
```

Then your `UpdateInventory` method should read `Id` instead of `GlitterId`:

```
public virtual void UpdateInventory<PurchasedEntity, Inventory>(
   IEnumerable<PurchasedEntity> purchaseDetails, 
   GenericRepository<Inventory> inventory, 
   Expression<Func<Inventory, bool>> filterForInventory) 
        where PurchasedEntity : IPurchasedEntity, class
        where Inventory : IPurchasedEntity, class, new()
{
    foreach (var item in purchaseDetails)
    {
        var inventory = new Inventory();
        inventory.Id = item.Id;
       // if you have more standard fields, define them in IPurchasedEntity
    }
}
```

**Update:**  After trying to infer your domain from `PurcahsedEntity` and `Inventory` it might make more sense to call `IPurchasedEntity` `IInventory` instead and define your common properties there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, same was suggested by @elgonzo, you can see our chat. I am accepting this as an answer but if elgonzo writes an  answer here then I will mark that one as the answer as he really put some time with me for solving this one...